# Converting Bitmap Image to Byte Array and Store into Mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, bitmap, blob

I am a nooby android developer and am trying to convert bitmap image into byte array and store that value in Mysql database.

The following code is working great and the value is stored in the database, but am not sure if this is the real image or not..

Here's the code am using to convert the image:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file_path);
         ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG,100, blob);

         bitmapdata = blob.toByteArray();

         //System.out.println(blob.toByteArray());

         bitmap.recycle();
         bitmap = null;

         photo_string = bitmapdata.toString();
         System.out.print(photo_string);
         try {
                blob.close();
                blob = null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();


}
```

and here's the HttpPost part:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("InsertIntoDB.php");
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("img",photo_string ));
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

The value stored in DB is something like: **[B@4285096**

is the really the image itself ??
Please help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The value you are seeing is the byte array for image.

Comment: Thank you so very much, i spent the whole day checking if it's the byte array or not... :) Thanks

Comment: @Izzo32: No it is not. Image data is not stored in db correctly.

Comment: Can you show the code how you are reading image data from the database?

Comment: but the thing that is saved in db is definately the byte array of a image

Comment: But what OP says is `value stored in DB is something like: [B@4285096`

Comment: @Ravinder still don't know how to read the byte array and convert it to image, and still didn't work on it...

Comment: That one is not a byte array *content* but a pointer to content.

Comment: yes trust me I have sent images over bluetooth by converting them into byte format and it is always shown in log like this only.

Comment: heres the way to get the image from a byte array code:                   Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(((byte[]) "your array"), 0, ((byte[]) "byte array").length, options);

Comment: Guys am not reading the value from database yet, am just storing it.

Comment: @Izzo32: Use the code given by AdityaAnand after reading from database and try to save or display the bitmap. If displayed as what is expected, then you can trust on what is stored in database.

Comment: after converting the image to byte array as mentioned in the question, i tried to converting it again using @Ravinder code and setting it to another image view it's working great and the same image shown... Thank you Ravinder for your help